# Salt block cooking coming out too salty

Tags: meat, salt

It's a lot of fun to cook on a salt block, but I find that when I cook meat on it, that the meat absorbs too much salt and taste badly salty. Especially if it is a smaller piece of meat, like a kabob.

Is there a solution for this? How can I cook smaller pieces of meat on a salt block without oversalting them?

Comment: Are you drying off the meat before you put it on the block?  (The meat will still squeeze out some moisture as it cooks, so you can dry it completely)

Comment: Have you considered ... a steel pan?